# how to get click event on list (autocomplete) in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to make auto-complete multi-select in react . But when `a` in input it shows me filtered list ,Now I want to get an event when I select any item from `list`

**is there any way to get an event when user selects an item from the list with it's selected value**

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-7iy8l

API LINK https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-clearable-multiple

```
<Dropdown
    clearable
    fluid
    multiple
    search
    selection
    options={countryOptions}
    placeholder='Select Country'
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `onChange` event on `Dropdown` and get the last item of the 
`value` array

```
<Dropdown
  onChange={(e, { value }) => console.log(value[value.length - 1])}
/>
```